# JSoup skipping elements Android 

Tags: java, android, httpresponse, jsoup, http-get

JSoup seems to be skipping some elements in my HTML string. I am 100% positive everything is in the HTML String, but JSoup is only reading some of the elements when I select them to be parsed, or none at all. But I know they exist. Here is my code: Thanks:

```
public void parseDoc() {
    final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, true);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
            "https://secure.groupfusion.net/processlogin.php");
    String HTML = "";
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("referral_page",
                "/modules/gradebook/ui/gradebook.phtml?type=student_view"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currDomain",
                "beardenhs.knoxschools.org"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username
                .getText().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password
                .getText().toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HTML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
        Element link = doc.select("a").first();
        String linkHref = link.attr("href");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        try {
            request.setURI(new URI(linkHref));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response = httpclient.execute(request);
        String html = "";
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        HTML = str.toString();
        doc = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
        Elements divs = doc.select("div.yuiTop");
        for (Element d: divs) {
            sting.append(d.text());
            sting.append("\n");
        }


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of weird code here... so I gather that this is making a query, which will return a list of hyperlinks as a result, and you are screen-scraping the result for the first hyperlink, then you are trying to load the content of that second link? Well, are you sure the server is returning a valid hyperlink? Try loading the page in your browser.

If it's valid then I'm not sure what the issue is, but why wouldn't you use `WebView.loadUrl()`, and let the browser component take care of it?

Comment: I have discovered the source of the problem but I do not know how to fix it. What I need to do is scrape the table from this specific page and print it to a TextView. I know I have to use JSoup for this, but it seems like JSoup cannot find every element on the page. Any idea? It can't find the table I need, the string always returns empty.

Comment: I just need to get the HTML of HTTPGEt. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `linkHref` is an empty string? In that case, maybe your `<a>` element has a blank `href` attribute. Or maybe you're selecting the wrong element, and you could narrow down your query if you know something about the `href` element. For example, if you knew the link should come from "domain.com," then you could query for "a[href*=domain.com]".

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue to a problem with JSoup. Everything is working now EXCEPT JSoup. For some reason JSoup is not parsing the whole document. I have checked the HTML String and everything is there. It's like JSoup is skipping some elements. Look at my new revised code at the top and see if you see an error where I am trying to select the elements.